# do I have to remove event listener when socket is disconnected?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

In socket.io, when the client is disconnected from the server the `disconnect` event is fired in the server for the socket. Do I have to `removeAllEventListeners()` from the socket `$events`? Or does it happen automatically when the socket dies? I heard that memory leaks can be on the server if i don't do it ...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After digging through the socket.io source, the socket object (which is the EventEmitter) is deleted when the client disconnects so it is not necessary to manually call removeAllListeners.

Comment: Is it possible to add the previous event listeners for forced new connection?
Without removing listeners is it possible to disconnect client?

Comment: after reconnection `.on('connect'` fires again and listeners inside callback of `.on('connect'` are assigned again. I just got this situation. Double listeners after 1 reconnection

Comment: @LukasLiesis, this thread is about what happens in the server part of the code (NodeJS), not on the client. On the client code you should not add events inside the "on('connect')" event or they will fire multiple times after reconnection.

Comment: @diegonunes can't check now but won't it happen on nodejs too? `.on('connect')` will fire each time connection happens, isn't it? Not sure what is your point. If you need to re-add listener on reconnection, why can't use `.on('connect')`? No matter if it's client or server.

Comment: @LukasLiesis, sorry if my comment was not clear enough. In the browser, you have a long-lived object for the socket connection (your individual connection) and if you add events like `socket.on('custom', ...)` INSIDE the `socket.on('connect', ...)` you will eventually get two identical events for the same `custom` message after reconnection.
In node.JS you have a new, "clean" socket object coming at every 'connect' event, even if it's from and old client reconnecting, so adding custom events inside the `on('connect', ...)` is actually the right way to add listen to events from your clients.

Comment: In the node.JS you don't even have access to the `socket` object before the client connect (obviously) and you don't have a "global" object to put your events (which would be copied over to the new sockets from clients), so you need to add events to each client after they connect. In the browser, even before connecting, you are able to set your custom events to listen to messages from the server, so you don't need to (and must not) add custom events on the inside the `connect` event.